# Print Contents of Array List

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-tree

Trying to Print the Contents of the Array List but only get the address and not the arraylist for this level order traversal program. How can I print its contents, and not the address of the code?

```
  public  static<T> void levelOrder(BinaryTree<T> t) 
  {         
      if(t == null)
         return;
      // create ArrayList of type Binary Tree
      ArrayList<BinaryTree<T>> level = new ArrayList<BinaryTree<T>>();
      // add root to the ArrayList
      level.add(t);
      // while there is at least one node
      while(!level.isEmpty())
      {
         BinaryTree<T> curr = new BinaryTree<T>();
         level.add(0,curr);
         // add the left node to ArrayList 
         if(curr.getLeft() != null)
            level.add(curr.getLeft());
         // add the right node to ArrayList 
         if(curr.getRight() != null)
            level.add(curr.getRight());
         // remove element at front of array list
         level.remove(0);  
      }
      System.out.println(level);
  }
```

I tried this toString method below but I receive an imcompatible type error:void cannot be compared with string

```
  public String toString(BinaryTree<T> t)
  {
     return levelOrder(t);
  }
```

This is the full class below:

```
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      public class BinaryTree<T> 
      {
          private T data;
          private BinaryTree<T> parent;
          private BinaryTree<T> left;
          private BinaryTree<T> right;
       // constructor
       public BinaryTree()
       {
          parent = left = right = null;
          data = null;
       }
       // make the root method         
       public void makeR(T data)
       {
          if (!isEmpty())
          {
             System.out.println("Can't make root. Already exists");
          }
       else
         this.data = data;
       }
     // set and get methods
     public void setData(T data)
     {
        this.data = data;
     }
     public void setLeft(BinaryTree<T> tree)
     {
         left = tree;
     }
     public void setRight(BinaryTree<T> tree)
     {
       right = tree;
     }
     public void setParent(BinaryTree<T> tree)
     {
       parent = tree;
     }   
     public T getData()
     {
       return data;
     }
     public BinaryTree<T> getParent()
     {
       return parent;
     }
     public BinaryTree<T> getLeft()
     {
       return left;
     }
     public BinaryTree<T> getRight()
     {
       return right;
     }
    // is Empty method
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
       if (data == null)
         return true;
       else
         return false;
    }
    public void attachLeft(BinaryTree<T> tree)
    {
       if (tree==null) return;
       else if (left!=null || tree.getParent()!=null)
       {
         System.out.println("Can't attach");
         return;
       }
       else
       {
            tree.setParent(this);
            this.setLeft(tree);
       }
    }
    public void attachRight(BinaryTree<T> tree)
    {
       if (tree==null) return;
       else if (right!=null || tree.getParent()!=null)
       {
           System.out.println("Can't attach");
           return;
       }
       else
       {
           tree.setParent(this);
           this.setRight(tree);
       }
    }
    // Level Order method
    public  static<T> void levelOrder(BinaryTree<T> t) 
    {         
       if(t == null)
         return;
    // create ArrayList of type Binary Tree
    ArrayList<BinaryTree<T>> level = new ArrayList<BinaryTree<T>>();
    // add root to the ArrayList
    level.add(t);
    // while there is at least one node
    while(!level.isEmpty())
    {
       BinaryTree<T> curr = new BinaryTree<T>();
       level.add(0,curr);
       // add the left node to ArrayList 
       if(curr.getLeft() != null)
          level.add(curr.getLeft());
       // add the right node to ArrayList 
       if(curr.getRight() != null)
          level.add(curr.getRight());
     // remove element at front of array list
     level.remove(0);  
    }
       //I tried a for loop but if I print it outside the while loop, nothing shows.
       //If I print it in the while loop, I get infinite loops. Not sure where I should
       //place the print statement.
      for(int i = 0; i < level.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(level.get(i));
 } 
public void String toString(BinaryTree<T> t)
{
  return levelOrder(t);
}
```

}

Comment: What is `BinaryTree`?  If you print a single `BinaryTree`, e.g. `System.out.println(new BinaryTree<Object>());`, what do you get?  It's likely your problem has nothing to do with `ArrayList`, as `ArrayList` has a sane [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method out of the box.

Comment: BinaryTree is the name of a generic class BinaryTree<T>. I'm not sure how to use the levelOrder method in a toString method so that I can show the contents of the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println on an object will call the toString method of this object.

The toString method of an ArrayList is a bracket containing the toString of each object,

The default implementation of toString is the adress of the object, what you need to do is to implement the toString method of the objects you add in your ArrayList

Comment: I understand the toString method but how would I implement or call the method name (levelOrder(BinaryTree<T> t) in the toString method so that it can show the contents?

Comment: Sure.                                                              I just need to find a way so that when I call the levelOrder method in the main program, I don't get an address as the result

Answer (score 0):

use this code in place of System.out.println(level);

```
ListIterator<Object> li=level.ListIterator();

while(li.hasNext()){
 System.out.println(((BinaryTree<T>)li.next()));

}
```

1)you need to override the toString() method in the class ,to which T is refering(if T refers to Primitive Wrapper Classes,then no need to Override toString()).
 2)also override the toString() in your BinaryTree class to display meaningful values according to your problem

Comment: or maybe I could use a for loop?

Comment: I tried the code but it seems it still couldn't find the list iterator class. I imported them at the beginning regardless.

Comment: Sure,You can use it.Better to use enhanced for loop.

Comment: Why would you use a `ListIterator` here and declare it of type `Object` only to cast the elements manually to `BinaryTree<T>`?  I can hardly think of a more convoluted way to print list elements on separate lines.

Comment: Because ArrayList.listIterator() returns an object of type ListIterator<Object>